# I want to conditional formatting A1:A25 cells based on another two cell values eg;if cell B1 and C1 contains word "off"then the cells become red

Tags: libreoffice-calc

if cells B1 and C1 contains word off then formatted cell become red in background colour and any of the two cells contains other value then green colour

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to give  red background colour of cellsA1:A25 if cell B1 and cell C1 both contains word "off",and if any of these cells contains any other value then the color of A1:A25 is green

Comment: Did you check the documentation? https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/guide/cellstyle_conditional.html and https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/images/d/d1/LibreOffice_Calc._Conditional_formatting_guide_EN.pdf , for example?